# ASP.NET Forms Authentication - Warn user when session is about to end

Tags: asp.net

I have an ASP.NET 3.5 app using Forms Authentication.

It would be nice to be able to warn a user that their login session will timeout. I'm thinking that it would require some AJAX / Jquery but thats as far as I've got.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could simply use [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/window.setTimeout) with a time period before session expiration and do something like alert() a minute or so before. So if you have a session timeout of 20 minutes you could make the alert show after 19 minutes of inactivity.

**Edit**- as others have suggested there are alternatives (probably better). Take a [look at this](http://www.primaryobjects.com/CMS/Article86.aspx) for one example.

Comment: If you are going to do this, why not make a no-op request to the server which will defer the timeout?

Comment: Because AJM didn't specify that the session needs to live on.

Comment: True, but the reason for warning the user in the first place would surely be to avoid the inconvenience of a timeout and consequent loss of session information.

Comment: Yes that is true. Additionally it highly unlikely that if a user hasn't used a Web app for 19 minutes they are actually going to be at their desk when the alert shows- which is why an alert is actually a poor solution!

Answer (score 2):

Typically, when would you inform the user? If you make a request (Ajax or otherwise) then the session will not timeout, because the very act of making a request will defer session timeout to a later time.